# How to prove the map $t\mapsto \text{ gauss with center } t$ is continuous?

Tags: inequality, continuity, operator-theory, gaussian

Let $k>0$ and $g_t$ be a gaussian-type function with center $t$ defined by $g_t(x):=e^{-k(x-t)^2}$  for all $x\in \mathbb R$. I intuitively observe that the map
$g: t\in \mathbb R \longrightarrow g_t\in L_\infty(\mathbb R)$ is **continuous**, i.e.
$$f(t):=\max_{x\in \mathbb R} |e^{-k(x-t)^2} -e^{-kx^2}|\rightarrow 0 \text{ if } t\rightarrow 0.$$

I think that we should find a good estimation to prove it. What I tried is to observe that $e^{-kx^2}\leq 1$, then $f(t)\leq \max_{x\in \mathbb R} |e^{2kxt-t^2} -1|$. But for each fixed $t\in \mathbb R$, the right-hand-side is infinity. So this estimation is useless. How do I do a better estimation?

Comment: @JasTer First, thank you for your comment! I think that your $O(t)$ is still involved with $x$.

Comment: I thought I deleted my comment, as I realized that I was in error ... so

Comment: So you are of course right. I started thinking what features of the translated function is needed in order to get continuity. Differentiability is not enough, one needs some kind of bound on the derivative. (Replace for example the gaussian by sin(x*x), which I don't think will give continuous translation.)

Comment: Here is an idea: $h(t) = g_t(x) - g(x)$ has exactly one max and min, and you can show that they are located at $\pm\sqrt{1/2} + O(t^2)$.

Comment: In the end you want to prove that $x\mapsto e^{-kx^2}$ is uniformly continuous. But this is true more generally for any function in $C_0$: On compact sets you are uniformly continuous and outside of compact sets you get as small as you want.

Comment: @MaoWao yes, It is indeed what I need, thank you so much for your hint!